# How to retrieve current page HTML code from Footer() method in TCPDF?

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf, fpdf

I'm using TCPDF to render some report generated through a sequence of HTML tables. These tables contain some tracking code I want to parse from Footer() method and add to current page footer. Any idea how to get the html code of the current page from TCPDF ?

I'm basically doing this:

```
class SVNPDF extends TCPDF {

        // Page footer
        public function Footer() {

            // Position at 15 mm from bottom
            $this->SetY(-15);
            // Set font
            $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 10);
            // Page number
            $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');

            $this->SetY(-15);
            $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 10);
            $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Picking #'.$glb_picking_num.'', 0, false, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');

            // HERE I NEED TO RETRIEVE CURRENT PAGE HTML CONTENT AND EXTRACT THE TRACKING NUMBER INSIDE FOR DISPLAY IN CURRENT FOOTER
        }
}

$report = 'SOME LONG HTML CODE HERE';
$pdf = new SVNPDF('L', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($report, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__) . '/test.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was to use the tag  to define a method I added to the SVNPDF class above. Then TCPDF will call this method with the tracking in parameter.

Here's a snapshot:

```
<tcpdf method="my_custom_func" params="'.TCPDF_STATIC::serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array('tracking number here')).'" />
```

and in SVNPDF class:

```
public function my_custom_func( $tracking_num ){
            $cur_page = $this->PageNo();
            // I can now store the $tracking_num in some private array and retrieve it in the Footer() as per current page number
        }
```